# Blog permalink pages missing formatting in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I've created a site/blog with Jekyll and it works great except that the individual blog pages `2012/03/14/title-of-blog-post.html` are not formatted, there is no  or css includes, just the `<p>`,`<h1>` tags got from processing markdown.

Is there something to be altered in the `_config.yml` to sort this, or do I need to add a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have basic YAML front matter the defines the layout at the start of your raw file. For example:

```
---
layout: default
---
```

Also, make sure that your source file is named with an extension that will get parsed. For example, to output:

```
2012/03/14/title-of-blog-post.html
```

Your source file should be:

```
_posts/2012-03-14-title-of-blog-post.md
```

It's probably one of those two things that's causing the issue.